# URLDownloadToFile does not work for some websites

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching for solutions online for a few days but failed. 
I want to download the picture from the URL below using `URLDownloadToFile` in Excel VBA. The code works for other websites but not the one below. It downloads the file which cannot be opened. I tried to open the URL in Chrome and save as JPG, it does not work either. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

[image: Image referred to above]

Comment: Did you try `https://fr.louisvuitton.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_AS/--FGKC15LVH900_PM2_Front%20view.jpg` instead?

Comment: yeah that is the one I tried. It does not work.